# PS: Set-ADAccountPassword - Complexity Exception

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I've got problems with setting new passwords via Powershell on Server 2012 R2:

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity testuser48 
-OldPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "HelloPassword123#" -Force)
-NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "April456#@123" -Force)
```

I tried many different passwords but there's always an `ADPasswordComplexityException`.

```
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:1325,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADAccountPasword
```

Are there any other things I could try?
All password complexity rules (incl. length, ...) are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I have to set both *minimum and maximum password age* from undefined to 0 in order for this command to work. That does not seem to be documented ...

Comment: Please write the command you are using

Answer (score 0):

Can you use -Reset instead of -OldPassword?  Try below to see if it works for you.  Also is this in a domain or a standalone server?

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity testuser48 -Reset
-NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "April456#@123" -Force)
```

Comment: yes, with `-Reset` it works, but we want to use the cmdlet without domain admin rights. 
it's a domain.

Comment: Ah, I forgot we ran into this same issue with not having the minimum and maximum password age defined.  Once we defined it our command started working.